# BAD : JAVA Math.sqrt(i) tends to 0

Tags: java

This code is giving me 0.00 as output, what's wrong?

```java
import java.lang.Math;

class Calculator
{
    double i;
    double x = Math.sqrt(i);
}


public class p_4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Calculator a=new Calculator();
        a.i=55;
        System.out.println("square root is "+a.x); // this is printing 0.00 why ?
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! `x` and `i` are initialized to 0. The value of `x` doesn't change when you modify `i`. Perhaps you would prefer calling a method on your `Calculator` object to compute the `sqrt` using the current value of `i`?

Comment: Math.sqrt is only called on initialization, not after you've assigned a value to i. Put it in a method with a parameter and call it when you want it calculated.

Comment: You can’t do it this way in Java; you need a method to compute the square root. (You could do this in C++ by the way).

Answer (score -1):

When you create new object of `Calculator` class using new keyword, both class level variables i and x are initialized considering default values. double i will be initialized with 0.0 and double x is initialized with resolving Math.sqrt(i) as 0.0 (where i is 0.0).

Till here i is 0.0 and x is 0.0. When at next line you assign 55 to i, then the updated value for i is 55. But the value of x is not re-calculated, so x is still 0.0.

If you want to get x updated to after after assigning new value to i. Either use setter method to set i and in that setter method update the value of x as well. Like:

```
public void setI(double i) {
     this.i = i;
     this.x = Math.sqrt(i);
}
```

or during printing of x, get the value of x using getter method. Like:

```
public double getX() {
     this.x = Math.sqrt(i);
     return x;
}
```

**As well as per OOPS concepts variable should be accessed using getter/setter methods and variable should be private.**